# Less bits changes but same PSNR value

Tags: image-processing, rgb, steganography

We have proposed and simulated an LSB insertion method that does 10% less bits changes then the regular LSB. However to our surprise the PSNR value of the proposed method is very close to the regular LSB ( around ~1% increase )

It is really confusing as our proposed method does less LSB changes but the PSNR value is still the same. Would appreciate any help.

We are using Matlab and testing on RGB image ( embeding on LSB of all three RGB channels )

Comment: You say you are embedding in the LSB but your value is *close* to the original value. Surely the LSB can only ever be zero or one, so how can you be *close* - surely the furthest away you could possibly be is one? Also, why do you want to increase the PSNR? What tools/environment are you using?

Comment: Our assumption is that since our proposed algorithm has 10% less LSB bits changed then the regular LSB the overall PSNR should be higher then regular LSB.  ( it shows only ~1% increase ). I'm really confused. Also I'm using Matlab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your results are not unexpected and that you're probably overestimating the effect because PSNR is a logarithmic function. I will plug in some numbers to show you that effect, but I will make some assumptions about details you haven't mentioned.

I assume that you embed only 1 bit per pixel and that is in the least significant bit and not in the 2nd, 3rd or any other.

What this means is that if a bit flips, the square error between the original and the modified pixel is 1. If we assume a stream of random bits, we expect to change half of the pixels where we embed our information. All of this can be encapsulated in the following two functions.

```
mse = @(bits, x, y) (0.5 * bits) / (x * y)
psnr = @(signal, noise) = 10 * log10(signal^2 / noise)
```

Where `bits` is the total number of embedding bits, `x` and `y` the size of the image, `signal` is the maximum intensity value in the original image (I used 255) and `noise` is the mse.

Let's assume a 512x512 image. For simplicity, let's also calculate the PSNR for only one colour component.

5,000 bits: 68.3368 db

4,500 bits: 68.7944 db

**PSNR increase**: 0.6696%

---

100,000 bits: 55.3265 db

90,000 bits: 55.7841 db

**PSNR increase**: 0.8271%

---

In fact, you can derive a general symbolic form.

```
mse_orig = (bits / 2) / (x * y) = bits / (2 * x * y)
mse_steg = (0.9 * bits / 2) / (x * y) = 0.9 * mse_orig

psnr = 10 * log10(signal^2 / mse)

percent_change = 100 * (psnr_steg - psnr_orig) / psnr_orig
```

By using the property `log(a / b) = log(a) - log(b)`, the above can be simplified to:

```
percent_change = 100 * (-log10(0.9) / log10(2* x * y * signal^2 / bits))
```

Where `bits` is the number of bits you embed with regular lsb embedding (i.e., 5,000 and NOT 4,500).

Comment: Amazing comprehensive answer. I salute you Reti!